# Logarithm of analytic function on non-open domain

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, logarithms, connectedness

I have a function $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ that is analytic on $A = \{s\mid \mathfrak{R}(s)\geq1\}$ and does not vanish on $A$.

Intuitively, I would expect this to mean that $f$ has an analytic logarithm on $A$, but I am not sure if that is true.

I know that it has a holomorphic logarithm on $\{s\mid\mathfrak{R}(s)>1\}$, since that is open and simply connected.

It is also clear that there exists an open set $B \supseteq A$ in which $f$ is holomorphic and does not vanish, but I am not sure if I can assume $B$ to be simply connected, so I cannot simply conclude that $f$ has a holomorphic logarithm on $B$.

It is also clear that, at every point on the $\mathfrak{R}(s) = 1$ line, I can find some open neighbourhood in which $f$ is holomorphic and does not vanish, so I can extend the logarithm of $f$ on $A$ to that neighbourhood analytically. But then I have a ‘different’ logarithm for each point on that line and I need to somehow stitch them together, which is not clear to me.

So my question is: Is my intuition correct? Can I somehow justify the existence of an analytic logarithm of $f$ on $A$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, because you can take $B$ to be the union of $A$ and a family of open disks with center on the imaginary axis, so that $B$ is simply connected.

Why is $B$ simply connected? Note that $z+x\in B$ for all $z\in B$ and $x>0$. So  given a closed curve in $B$ you can shrink it to a point by first pushing it to the right until it lies in the open right half-plane, then shrinking it to a point there. (Or: $B$ is *contractible*...)

Comment: That seems reasonable, but I don't know enough topology to see what theorems you are using here. Why does this imply that $B$ is simply connected?

Comment: @ManuelEberl See edit

Comment: Ah, interesting. That seems very reasonable to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is true. In fact, if $A\subset\mathbb C$ is open and connected, then $A$ is simply connected if and only if every analytic function $f\colon A\longrightarrow\mathbb C$ has an analytic logarithm. See, for instance, theorem 2.2 in John B. Conway's *Functions of One Complex Variable I*.

Comment: I don't see how that relates to my problem. I don't know if my $B$ is simply connected (i.e. if I can pick it such that it is simply connected); that's the entire problem.

Comment: @ManuelEberl Your set $A$ *is* simply connected and you wrote “I would expect this to mean that $f$ has an analytic logarithm on $A$, but I am not sure if that is true”. How can you think that my answer is not related to your problem?

Comment: It is simply connected, but it is not open.

Comment: @ManuelEberl You are right! But then I would say that your problem makes no sense, because *by definition* (at least, that's the usual definition) the domain of an analytic function is an open set. I'm sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: Ah, I see. I should clarify that. What I meant is that $f$ is holomorphic on some open superset of $A$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Actually "analytic" and "holomorphic" are not quite synonymous. The domain of a _holomorphic_ function is open by definition. The usual definition is that $f$ is analytic on $E$ if for every $z\in E$ there exists $r>0$ such that $f$ is, or can be extended so as to be, holomorphic in $D(z,r)$. So the question does make sense...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I got it. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your effort in any case! I did not mean to sound harsh above. :)

Comment: @ManuelEberl You didn't sound harsh.